# Wubi SATA Drive Problems

Tags: ubuntu, sata

I installed Wubi on my 1TB Sata drive. Windows still works fine but Wubi won't boot. I believe this has to do with the sata drive?

Ubuntu installed on a seperate partition works, but I would prefer Wubi.

Comment: Do you have any error messages? Did ubuntu appeared in Windows boot manager?

Answer (score 1):

Wubi uses the Windows boot loader, so you may want to double check the settings, which you can find in System I believe. Also, Wubi Ubuntu installs live in a large file within your windows partition, so make sure that that file hasn't been moved or damaged.

Answer (score 0):

**This is probably not the type of question you should ask here**

There are however, lots of places that will help you.
I myself would start at the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) and then if you can't find the information there, ask in the Ubuntu  IRC 'chat' room on [Freenode](http://freenode.net/)

- https://serverfault.com/faq
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1504/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-it-questions

Answer (score 0):

Since Wubi, as mentioned, is just a big file on your Windows partition, it might be impacted by fragmentation. It did with me once - I defragmented and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Ubuntu on WUBI for the past month or so on my desktop and my laptop, ever since 9.10 came out.  While I have been extremely happy with Linux, I just had it refuse to boot and had to reinstall for the third time last night.  Defrag and chkdsk /r did not work for me.  Fortunately, getting Ubuntu up and running is relatively easy, but I'm starting to feel pretty turned off by wubi.  It's awesome for what it does, but at this point it's just not ready to work as a serious dual-boot alternative imo